# Adding a Second Service to an Angular Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know if you can add a second service to an angular module?

It seems when I try, I end up breaking angular.

**This Works:**

```
var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule',[]);

MyModule.service('MyService',function(){
    this.message = 'checking in'; 
});

MyModule.controller('MyController', function($scope,MyService){
    console.log(MyService.message);
});

// output
// checking in
```

**This DOES work: I had an issue elsewhere in my code.  I'm leaving this up because it is still hard to find angular documentation with two services being applied (which I promise I looked for)**

```
var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule',[]);

MyModule.service('MyService',function(){
    this.message = 'checking in'; 
});
MyModule.service('MyServiceTwo',function(){
    this.message = 'checking in'; 
});

MyModule.controller('MyController', function($scope,MyService,MyServiceTwo){
    console.log(MyService.message);
});


// no output
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? This is working fine in 1.2.18

Comment: Weird... maybe I am missing something else and my simple example DOES work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second service definition just retrieve the module - don't redefine it:

```
var MyModule = angular.module('MyModule');
```

Comment: I'm sorry... I think I wasn't clear.  I'm not defining it in the second example.  That's just another code block to represent the whole sha-bang.  Edited the example to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Your code looks fine to me. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: It does work... I had an issue elsewhere... thank you for your time.